# TYPO3 10 <f:cObject/> does NOT render first content-element from tt_content table after clearing cache

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-10.x

I am currently facing the issue, that when I fetch content from a specific page via typoscript, I only get the full content **after the second pageload** if I have deleted all caches before. The first content element is not rendered at all (seems to be ignored).

Here is my Typoscript:

```
lib.dynamicContent = COA
lib.dynamicContent {
    5 = LOAD_REGISTER
    5 {
        colPos.cObject = TEXT
        colPos.cObject {
            field = colPos
            ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
            ifEmpty.cObject {
                value.current = 1
                ifEmpty = 0
            }
        }
        pageUid.cObject = TEXT
        pageUid.cObject {
            field = pageUid
            ifEmpty.data = TSFE:id
        }
        contentFromPid.cObject = TEXT
        contentFromPid.cObject {
            data = DB:pages:{register:pageUid}:content_from_pid
            data.insertData = 1
        }
        wrap.cObject = TEXT
        wrap.cObject {
            field = wrap
        }
    }
    20 = CONTENT
    20 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
            orderBy = sorting
            where = {#colPos}={register:colPos}
            where.insertData = 1
            pidInList.data = register:pageUid
            pidInList.override.data = register:contentFromPid
        }
        stdWrap {
            dataWrap = {register:wrap}
            required = 1
        }
    }
    90 = RESTORE_REGISTER
}
```

This is how I render the content in fluid:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{pageUid: '41', colPos: '1'}" />
```

The output from the first content element after clearing the cache is on the first pageload: `<div />`. When I reload the page, I get the full content from the page.

I already checked the database queries which are executed, but they are always the same and return the correct results.

---

System:

TYPO3 10.4.8

PHP 7.3

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `stdWrap` part, which contains a `wrap`, that should be created via plain HTML in your Fluid template instead.

Im not 100% sure, but I guess the `required` check within that `stdWrap` section disables the content as well, since it might be checked before the actual content has been rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that didn't help. I tested the code on another project and there everything works fine. There must be something else which causes this issue.